# Cannot scroll inside a <div> whose parent is <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one program called scroll1.html which has the div scrolling when the mouse moves ovel an image. In the second program called scroll2.html, I want the  inside the  to scroll but it doesnt work.

Scroll1.html : Working Version ------------------------------------------------

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div, scrollTop, scrollID, direction, imgDirection, scrollID1;
        function scroll() {
            if (direction > 150) {
                if (scrollTop != 0)
                    scrollTop--;
            }
            else {
                if (scrollTop != (div.scrollHeight - 300))
                    scrollTop++;
            }
            div.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            scrollID = setTimeout("scroll()", 10);
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            div = document.getElementById("containerDiv");
            div1 = document.getElementById("Div1");
            scrollTop = div.scrollTop;
        };
        function scrollOnImage() {
            if (imgDirection ==1 ) {
                if (scrollTop != 0)
                    scrollTop--;
            }
            else if (imgDirection == 2) {
            if (scrollTop != (div1.scrollHeight - 300))
                    scrollTop++;
            }
            div1.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            scrollID1 = setTimeout("scrollOnImage()", 10);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left">
        <div id="containerDiv" style="height: 300px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;" 
        onmousemove="direction=event.clientY - div.offsetTop;"
        onmouseout="clearTimeout(scrollID)" 
        onmouseover="direction=event.clientY - div.offsetTop; scroll()">
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left"> 
        <div id="Div1" style="height: 300px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;" >
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
            dummy content dummy content dummy content dummy content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left"> 
    <img src="http://www.easyvoyage.co.uk/base/imgs/default/esv/meh/upDownArrow.png" onmouseout="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onmouseover="imgDirection=1; scrollOnImage()" /><br /><br />
    <img src="http://www.easyvoyage.co.uk/base/imgs/default/esv/meh/downUpArrow.png" onmouseout="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onmouseover="imgDirection=2; scrollOnImage()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Scroll2.html : Not working -------------------------------------------

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div, scrollTop, scrollID, direction, imgDirection, scrollID1;

        window.onload = function() {
            div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
            scrollTop = div1.scrollTop;
        };
        function scrollOnImage() {
            if (imgDirection ==1 ) {
                if (scrollTop != 0)
                    scrollTop--;
            }
            else if (imgDirection == 2) {
            if (scrollTop != (div1.scrollHeight - 300))
                    scrollTop++;
            }
            div1.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            scrollID1 = setTimeout("scrollOnImage()", 10);

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<br />
<div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left; height:300px; max-height:300px; width:200px; overflow: hidden;" > 
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="height:20px;"><input type="image" src="images/LGbtn_off.png" alt="img1" onMouseOut="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onMouseOver="imgDirection=1; scrollOnImage()" /></th>
      <th>1A</th>
      <th ><input type="image" src="images/RRbtn_off.png" alt="img2" onMouseOut="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onMouseOver="imgDirection=2; scrollOnImage()" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="height:280px; max-height:280px;">
        <div id="div1">
          <ul id="ulR_1A" class="ulli">
              <li><span class="li_head">PCode:</span> 1234</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Product:</span> GX12x24 Medium Large 80</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Qty:</span> 256</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Batch No:</span> 01AC950</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Manf Date:</span> 11/08/2012</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">SS Date:</span>11/07/2013</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Total Pals:</span> 60</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Pals Occupied:</span> 59</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Occupancy:</span> 89%</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Trn No:</span> 1234567890</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Status:</span> Part Full</li>
          </ul>  
          <ul id="ulR_1A" class="ulli">
              <li><span class="li_head">PCode:</span> 1235</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Product:</span> GX12x24 Medium Large 80</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Qty:</span> 256</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Batch No:</span> 01AC950</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Manf Date:</span> 11/08/2012</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">SS Date:</span>11/07/2013</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Total Pals:</span> 60</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Pals Occupied:</span> 59</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Occupancy:</span> 89%</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Trn No:</span> 1234567890</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Status:</span> Part Full</li>
          </ul>  
          <ul id="ulR_1A" class="ulli">
              <li><span class="li_head">PCode:</span> 1236</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Product:</span> GX12x24 Medium Large 80</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Qty:</span> 256</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Batch No:</span> 01AC950</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Manf Date:</span> 11/08/2012</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">SS Date:</span>11/07/2013</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Total Pals:</span> 60</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Pals Occupied:</span> 59</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Occupancy:</span> 89%</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Trn No:</span> 1234567890</li>
              <li><span class="li_head">Bin Status:</span> Part Full</li>
          </ul>          
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</div>
<div style="border: solid 1px red; float: left"> 
    <img src="http://www.easyvoyage.co.uk/base/imgs/default/esv/meh/upDownArrow.png" onMouseOut="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onMouseOver="imgDirection=1; scrollOnImage()" /><br /><br />
    <img src="http://www.easyvoyage.co.uk/base/imgs/default/esv/meh/downUpArrow.png" onMouseOut="clearTimeout(scrollID1)" onMouseOver="imgDirection=2; scrollOnImage()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help out.

Comment: IMHO, a `div`s parent should never be a `td`.

Answer (score 0):

you have the `height`, `max-height`, `overflow` attributes on the `TD` but in order to make this work, they need to be on the `DIV`, such as:

```
<div id="div1" style="height:280px; max-height:280px; overflow:hidden">
```